# How to set collider with world bounds (Phaser)?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm using Phaser.io

I just learned how to set a collider function:

```
this.physics.add.collider(enemies, platforms, function (enemy) {
  enemy.destroy();
  gameState.score += 10;
});
```

But I would like to do the same thing without the platform. Instead of the platform, I would like to use the world bounds.

I know you can set world bounds like this:

```
player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
```

I've tried:

```
this.physics.add.collider(enemies, this.worldBounds, function (enemy) {
  enemy.destroy();
  gameState.score += 10;
});
```

But this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution for you:

**First**, set your enemy's sprite to collide with the **[setCollideWorldBounds(true)](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#setCollideWorldBounds__anchor)** like so:

```
enemy.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
```

**Second**, turn the option for your enemy's sprite  to listen for **[WorldBound events](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#onWorldBounds__anchor)** like so:

```
enemy.body.onWorldBounds = true;
```

**Third & lastly**, set the **["wordbounds" event listener](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Events.html#event:WORLD_BOUNDS__anchor)** & make the enemy disappear like so:

```
enemy.body.world.on('worldbounds', function(body) {
  // Checks if it's the sprite that you'listening for
  if (body.gameObject === this) {
    // Make the enemy sprite unactived & make it disappear
    this.setActive(false);
    this.setVisible(false);
  }
}, enemy);
```